# while-loop not working properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I want to create a page, where I can create Keys, and save them in a databank, but I got some problems.

There is a textfield, where you can write in, how many keys you want to create. For example I write 5 in, but it does only 3 entrys in the databank, but down in the code is an echo command, which says that he did it 5 times, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Also, what I noticed is, that the website is doing max 3 entrys in the databank, for example I write 10, and he still only does 3 entrys.
If I write only 1-3 keys, the while-loop is working.

```
echo "<p><a href='key.php'>Betakey administration</a></p>";

echo "<form action='#' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='number' name='numberkeys' placeholder='Number of Keys'>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='createkey' value='Create Key'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='keyanzeigen' value='Show all Keys'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='unusedkeys' value='Show all unused Keys'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='usedkeys' value='Show all used Keys'>";
echo "</form>";

$createdkeys=0;

if(isset($_POST['createkey'])){


  $minus= array(5,10,15);

  while($createdkeys<$_POST['numberkeys']){

  //creation of the keys
  for($i=1;$i<20 ;$i++){

    if(in_array($i,$minus)){
      $key=$key."-";
    }
    else{       
      $key=$key.mt_rand(0,9);
    }

    //the key looks like this: 1234-5678-1234-5678

  }


  //here it checks, if the key already exists
  $check = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT keyy FROM keyys WHERE keyy='$key'");
  $check = mysqli_fetch_array($check);

  //if the code not exists, the website will insert the key in the databank  
  //the website will echo the variable $createdkeys and increase the variable $createdkeys by one
  if(!isset($check)){
    $createdkeys= $createdkeys+1;
    echo "<p>".$createdkeys."</p>";
    mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO keyys VALUES('$key','NO')"); 
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: How and when loop ends

Comment: You are always concatenating $key to itself, which seems odd. You need to reset it. You should echo the key right before you do the DB check, to make sure they're actually different from each other.